# What do we call the inverse of a right-multiplication when it's the left-multiplication of the inverse element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, noncommutative-algebra, binary-operations, nonassociative-algebras

I'm working with a non-commutative, non-associative, *non-unital* algebra with objects that are somewhat like matrices, but have the property that for almost all $X$ (except the "zero-like" elements), there exists a unique element $X'$ such that for all $A$, $X'AX = XAX' = A$ and $X'' = X$. However, there is no similar element $X^*$ such that for all $A$, $(AX)X^* = A$.

> I know there are "right-inverses" and "left-inverses", but is there a name for when the inverse element has to be on the opposite side in order to undo the operation?

Also, I'm referring to inverse elements which isn't strictly accurate according to Wikipedia, but really, these are just elements which reverse multiplication by $X$, but only if on the opposite side of the operation.

Comment: I would strongly advice you to use $X’$ instead of $X^{-1}$; as you can see from the answers, people are confusing this with an actual inverse. What you have is that given $A$, for almost all $X$ there exists a unique $X’$ such that $XAX’ = A$ and $X’AX=A$.

Comment: Does the $X^{-1}$ you have depend only on $X$, or on both $X$ and $A$? If the latter, you should definitely call it something that reflects the dependence, such as $f(X,A)$ or something like that....

Comment: (No, I don’t think there is a name for such an element; it is vaguely reminiscent of the formulas for pseuoinverses, but not quite right for that either)

Comment: That's a good point, I've changed the notation and added a note.

Comment: $X'$ can be calculated directly from $X$.

Comment: Okay, then $X’$ (or something like that which does not use the ${}^{-1}$ notation) is a good notation, reminiscent of the pseudoinverse. So, for almost all $X$ there exists a unique $X’$ such that for for all $A$, $XAX’ = A$ and $X’AX=A$? You should phrase it that way, lest it seem to imply dependence on $A$.

Comment: Yes, sorry; but my point is that by mentioning $A$ first, you are implying that $X’$ depends on both $A$ and $X$. If it does not depend on $A$, you should mention the latter last. That said, I’m afraid I don’t have an answer to your actual question.

Comment: I deleted my last comment because I remembered that $X'' = X$. I've fixed what you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

If $e$ is an identity element of **(S,*)** (i.e., **S** is a unital magma) and $a \times b = e$, then $a$ is called a left inverse of $b$ and $b$ is called a right inverse of $a$. If an element $x$ is both a left inverse and a right inverse of $y$, then $x$ is called a two-sided inverse, or simply an inverse, of $y$.

Comment: I should clarify, there are no identity elements in this algebra, but multiplication can still be reversed by multiplying with a unique element.

Comment: Is your $a\ x\ b = e$ meant to be $a\times b=e$? Because you use $x$ later to represent an element; and if they are three elements, then $axb=e$ does *not* yield that $a$ is a left inverse of $b$ and $b$ a right inverse of $a$. Use `\times` for $\times$; do not use `x`.

Comment: Also, what the OP has is that given $a$, for every $b$ there exists a unique $b’$ such that $bab’ = a$ and $b’ab=a$.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question being posed.

Comment: thank you everyone for pointing out my mistakes, i will try to change my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the commutator.

Depending on the definition that you use, you essentially have that almost all A have a corresponding element X such that the commutator [A,X] is the identity element.

$[A,X] = AXA^{-1}X^{-1}$

(Sorry about formatting I typed this on my phone)

Comment: I've updated my post to clarify that my algebra does not have identity.